# RESTful API URLs and Denial Of Service attacks

Tags: web-application, denial-of-service, rest

I overheard the following statement today:

> We shouldn't use /api (e.g. in a RESTful URL like /api/v1/users/get) in our RESTful URLs anymore because it makes it easier for people to Denial Of Service attack our site. If we just give it a name like /users/get then people will be less likely to think it's an API and therefore won't be bothered DOS'ing us.

I thought this was a crazy statement and pointed out that large websites like Twitter use this same URL format, to which the person replied

> Just because they do it doesn't mean it's ok

Is there any merit whatsoever in this person's statement? I completely disagree with him. I would say that if someone was that intent on DOS attacking our site then a different URL format in our API certainly isn't going to stop them!

Comment: Assuming you correctly hash password (slow algorithm) your login form would be a nice URL to request unless you have a very solid throttling in place for individual clients AND site wide based on the number of failed login atempts in a certain time interval.

Comment: If it's an API, you probably have documentation online somewhere on how to access it.  If someone is running a DDOS they determine the best target, it's unlikely they would miss an API no matter what it's named if it incurred lots of resource usage.

Comment: I'm not even clear on why a REST API would somehow be a target for attack, but your "web browser" API wouldn't. Also how the latter would be somehow more effective for a DDOS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

His suggestion is merely [Security by Obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). As you point out a determined attacker would not be much impaired by this and it risks giving you a false sense of security.

If you are concerned about denial of service attacks you should investigate more robust solutions.

Schneier's opinion on the matter:

> I used to decry secret security systems as "security by obscurity." I now say it more strongly: "obscurity means insecurity."

https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2014/02/the_insecurity_2.html (February 14, 2014)